# Plotting large data with small patterns with imshow hides data

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

My data consists of large 2-d arrays.  When visualising this data with matplotlib's imshow, small datapoints or interesting features are not displayed.

I've tried all interpolation options for imshow, but none gave me the desired result.

As an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_array = np.zeros((10000, 10000))
my_array[5000, :] = np.ones(10000)

plt.imshow(my_array, aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

Ideally, I would be able to see the line at 5000 on the y-axis, yet nothing is displayed (I'm assuming this is due to the down-sampling).  Ideally, I would like a 'maximum' down-sampling method: rather than choosing the value of the nearest pixel, display the maximum value of any datapoint that would otherwise be hidden.